# How to compare string value by index and column and apply AND OR logic within dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, string-comparison

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   col1
0  ofcourse
1  I love the service
```

The dataframe could also have this value for row 1:

```
   col1
0  ofcourse
1  I hate the service
```

I want to compare the value of the strings by row and column and be able to check for one of two values in row1.

I want to create this logic:

```
if df.col1.loc[[0]] =='Of course!' and (df.col1.loc[[1]]=='I love the service' or df.col1.loc[[1]]=='I hate the service'):
    print('good')
```

When I run the logic above I get error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the []

```
df.col1.loc[0] =='Of course!' and (df.col1.loc[1]=='I love the service' or df.col1.loc[1]=='I hate the service')
```

Why it happen :

`df.loc[[0]]` will return the `DataFrame`, Since that is `DataFrame` when you did condition here, it will return the `DataFrame`, which will raise the errors

and

`df.loc[0]` will return the `Series`

---

More Info

```
type(df.loc[[0]])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
type(df.loc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: @RustyShackleford happy coding